# Javascript Prime Number Function Console Issue

Tags: javascript, primes

Apologies if this has been covered somewhere. I've searched through a lot of prime number function answers on here but I cannot seem to find the answer to my issue. I have cobbled together a function to check if a number is prime, and then I'm running a for loop for numbers under 100 and printing out primes. My code does not print primes. It seems to start printing primes, but then throws a 9 in there, and it gets worse from there.

I found code that is seemingly identical to mine that successfully prints primes to the console. Below is my code; where is my error? For the record I am using jsfiddle, and I am very new at this.

```
function isPrime(number) {
  if (number < 2) {
    return false;
  }
  for (var i = 2; i < number; i++) { 
    if (number % i == 0) { 
      return false;
    } else {
      return true;
      }
  }
};

for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
  if(isPrime(i)) {
   console.log(i);
  }
}
```

Comment: One "speed" improvement for this slow method of determining prime ... only need to loop up to `Math.sqrt(number);` - not an issue with such small numbers though

Answer (score 0):

You return true as soon as `number` is not divisible by `i`. Move your `return true` to the end:

```
function isPrime(number) {
    if (number < 2) return false;

    for (var i = 2; i < number; i++) { 
        if (number % i == 0) return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

You only want to return true when you didn't find an `i` that divides `number`.

Comment: Thank you! That makes it work! Also, good point Jaromanda X, I will fix that as well.

Comment: sorry, wasn't thinking straight, comment removed

Comment: @jaromanda-x Thanks. You may also remove the downvote if it is from you ;-)

Comment: @Frances you're welcome to accept the answer if it worked.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function isPrime(number) {
  var result = true;
  if (number < 2) {
    result = false;
  }
  for (var i = 2; i < number; i++) { 
    if (number % i == 0) { 
      result = false;
    }
  }
  return result;
};

for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
  if(isPrime(i)) {
   console.log(i);
  }
}
```

Comment: yes you've corrected it; but you made it much much worse, speed-wise, when you replaced `return false` with `result=false`.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is in

```
if (number % i == 0) { 
  return false;
} else {
  return true;
}
```

As you return something in every case (true or false), your algorithm exits on every first cycle.

You should not return anything in the else statement :

```
if (number % i == 0) { 
  return false;
} else {
  // continue the for statement.
}
```

And get the function to return true after the *for*.

For the joke, a much faster algorithm would be :

```
function isPrime(number) {
    var primes=[2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37, 41, 43, 47, 53, 59, 61, 67, 71, 73, 79, 83, 89, 97];
    if (primes.indexOf(number) > -1) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
};
```

Answer (score -2):

```
function isPrime(number) {
var check=true;
  if (number < 2) {
    return false;
  }
  for (var i = 2; i < number; i++) { 
    if (number % i == 0) { 
      check=false;
    } 
  }
   return check;
};

for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
  if(isPrime(i)) {
   console.log(i);
  }
}
```

Comment: No! You may not set check back to true once it has been set to false.